# Two SSH on the routers (Jumphost)

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script allowing me to SSH to one router first (which is a jumphost) and from there I want to SSH to another router.

*ssh on terminal @ current device to Router A (Jumphost)*

*ssh on Router A to Router B*

Can anyone help me how the bash script would look alike?

Regards,

Comment: `ssh -t userA@routerA ssh -t userB@routerB` ?

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do but for some unknown reasons it is not working. I am able to jumphost by this but my key is not passed for the second ssh. 

If I do this in two ssh commands, it works but not together. Any idea why?

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can start a program in background and talk to it with shell scripts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Is the entire purpose of the script to give you an interactive session on Router B? If so, just add a `ProxyCommand` to your `.ssh/config`, and you won’t even need a script. If you do need it in a script [just use the `-J` option](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two).

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a shell script. It's just a ssh configuration:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
Host router1
  Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx

Host router2
  Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p router1
```

With that config, you can connect to router2 through router1:

```
ssh router2
```